# Is it possible to wrap the heading of a column of an attribut table within the print composer?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, print-composer

The "wrap text on" function seems not to work for the heading of the columns, only for the rows.

I'm using QGIS 2.14.4

Comment: I don't think that is possible yet. But would be interesting.

Comment: @AlexandreNeto please post your comment as an answer so this thread can be marked as solved

Answer (score 5):

**Update for QGIS 3**

As of January 14, 2020, there's an outstanding request for this feature:  [Composer Attribute Table: Wrap Heading Text #30441](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/30441)

So it looks like the answer is still no. However, anyone interested should watch the linked feature request page for updates.

**Update for QGIS 3.12.3 and above:**

The feature is now implemented. Make sure to set the option "wrap text" and especially set the column width to a *fixed value*. It wont wrap the heading text if its set to *automatically*.

Comment: It is working now, I tested on 3.16  with oversized text set to wrap text on appearance settings and don't forget to set manual column width on attributes settings on main properties.

Comment: @Husni Please post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that is possible yet, but it would be very interesting feature to have.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/94487)

Comment: @ArMoraer Saying that something is not possible does answer the question.

Comment: The question was if it was possible to do something. It's not. There's no other answer IMHO.