# Is it possible to wrap text in column headers in print composer tables using QGIS 3.x?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, print-composer

Is it possible to wrap text in the header of an attribute table in print composer in QGIS 3.x?  There are options for wrapping text in the cells within the body, but they don't seem to work for the headers.
Other questions on stack exchange indicate it was not possible in previous versions, but all of the questions/answers are several years old, and there has been significant progress since then.  (This question, for example: [Is it possible to wrap the heading of a column of an attribut table within the print composer?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/206654/))
I'm using version 3.8.3 (Zanzibar)

I've tried both adding `\n` to the attribute heading, and setting the "wrap text on" box to * and adding that to the header.  Both of these approaches work within the body of the attribute tables.

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like the answer is still no. I posted an updated answer to the question you linked to, and merged your question with that one. (This keeps the site tidy and makes it easier for everyone to find the information they're looking for.)

Comment: I would give your columns shorter names in the 'Headings' column in the 'Attributes / Select Attributes' dialogue in the attribute table settings in the print composer window...